# Interface not implemented with dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple counter app, to which I would like to add a metric by implementing a metrics interface, but I am receiving a not implemented exceptions when using the metric.

```
using System;
using Foo.Metrics; // This contains the interface "IFooMetrics" and class "MetricCounter"

namespace FooService
{
    class Program
    {
        private static MetricCounter _myMetric;

        public Program(IFooMetrics fooMetrics)
        {
            _myMetric = fooMetrics.CreateMetric();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var counter = 0;
            var max = args.Length != 0 ? Convert.ToInt32(args[0]) : -1;

            while (max == -1 || counter < max)
            {
                counter++;
                Console.WriteLine($"Counter: {counter}");

                _myMetric.AddToCounter();
                Console.WriteLine("Metric added");

                System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately my knowledge of Dependency Injection is little, so I don't understand why its not working.

I simply want this metric to be initialized properly, but I am not sure what I'm not doing or doing wrong.

Comment: You need to share the code of `CreateMetric` method and `AddToCounter` method. Which line of code gives the error?

Comment: Initializing static filed in instance constructor is ... *unusual* approach. But to really see what is happening we need [mcve].

Comment: I will recreate the code example, thanks. But regarding the static field, I am unsure of how to achieve what I want without it as Main is static..?

Comment: I cannot see any line of code which will cause any dependency injection. This will not happening until you code this DI

Comment: I think you have not configured the DI in the code yet, so explicitly invoke the `new Program()` in the `Main()` to initialize the `_myMetricField`.

Comment: Dependency Injection is not part of C#, it is a technique, but not built in. As such, merely declaring your constructor to take your dependency is not enough, you need something that *actually injects this dependency*. In other words, you need to use a dependency container, configure this, then resolve Program, which would then inject your dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple injector nuget package for example is easy .This is the documentation for simple injector [simple injector doc](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/consoleintegration.html)

and here is a simple example
[example](http://anthonygiretti.com/2018/01/13/injection-dependency-bring-your-own-container-in-net-core-console-app-example-with-simple-injector/)

First of all you must create the class MetricCounter which implement the interface IFooMetrics.
Then create a container which register in the class with the interface as the example

```
private static readonly Container container;



static Program()
{
    container = new Container();

    container.Register<IFooMetrics, MetricCounter >();


    container.Verify();
}
```

and then in main

```
var service = container.GetInstance<IFooMetrics>();
service.YourMethod();
```